# PyQt problems with Spyder on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu-14.04, spyder

I've installed the latest version of Anaconda. The install went smoothly, but when I try to run Spyder I get a couple of run-time errors relating to PySide and PyQt. The final error message is:

```
RuntimeError: Please check Spyder installation requirements:
PyQt4 4.6+ (or PySide 1.2.0+) is required.
```

However, when I try to install PyQt, Ubuntu says I have the most up to date version. Also, `conda list` indicates that I have the following installed (I've excluded the other stuff as it isn't relevant):

```
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py35_1  
qt                        4.8.7                         1
```

So Ubuntu seems to recognise that I have PyQt installed, but Spyder can't 'see' it.

To fix this, I attempted to install spyder3 via the package manager using

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

The install completed without any errors, but running `spyder3` led to the same PyQt error as before.

Could someone please advise me how to fix this? I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so am not sure how to link Spyder to the required Qt files.

Comment: Did  you try installing spyder with anaconda?

Comment: @cowlicks thanks for the reply. I did install anaconda3, but spyder didn't work. I also tried the package manager - but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix this and figured it was worth posting an update in case anyone else has the same issue.

After installing Anaconda I installed some 3rd party software (moose framework) which requires a series of modules to be loaded. One of these is miniconda.

The presence of miniconda seems to confuse Spyder - and stops it from working. By using:
module unload miniconda
I found that Spyder works as normal.